# UISearchController messes with Layout of Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am using a `UISearchController` in my application following [this](https://www.veasoftware.com/posts/uisearchcontroller-in-swift-xcode-7-ios-9-tutorial) tutorial:

Now having set up a custom `UITableViewCell`. The `UISearchController` messes with my cells.

It seems like the `UISearchController` is not using the same custom `UITableViewCell` and it's view bounds differ from my own `UITableView`. Is there a way to change this back, when I press the cancel button?

**Edit:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though, nobody has answered, I found a solution:

1. make sure, your cell is connected to the actual tableView, not your primary only. ( I have used an Outlet and set only the cells of my outlet )
2. make sure you ALWAYS address the outlets in your custom cell. Since I used this

   cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"

my cell will automatically be cast to the default cell.